# Attempting to use <iframe> tag to embed YouTube videos

Tags: variables, iframe, playlist

I am using the following line of code to embed a YouTube player onto a new webpage. I've got over 200 videos online from 50 or so different performers. I'd like to create a page with all of the performers listed and then when you click on that performer's name their playlist will pop into a solo YouTube player. I can't seem to find a way to exchange the list=PLplaylist_ID to a variable that can be passed when the viewer clicks on a particular name. I need to use the  tag due to the flash-not-playing-on-iPad-issue :)

> iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="853" height="480"
>   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PLplaylist_ID&modestbranding=1&rel=0&autohide=1"
>   frameborder="0" />

Any help would be appreciated!
Ron

Answer (score 0):

iframe never will play video for you. 
It is just HTML container. What u need is launch html page inside iframe with YouTube player code inside.
For that You can try native Video TAG with fallback to flash (long way, reinvent bicycle ) or you can try to load in iframe : http://flowplayer.org. or http://videojs.com/